# What is the pattern matrix equivalent of ST_Equals()?

Tags: de-9im, ogc-sfa, ogc-sfs

Within the [OGC Simple Feature Access Part 1](https://portal.ogc.org/files/?artifact_id=25355), I found this:

[image]

Whereas, in PostGIS `(3.4.0dev 3.3.0rc2-335-gae95dd219`):

```sql
SELECT ST_RelateMatch(
        ST_Relate(
            'LINESTRING(1 1, 2 2)',
            'LINESTRING(1 1, 2 2)'
        ),
        'TFFFTFFFT'
) AS relmatch;
 relmatch 
----------
 t
```

but it returns `False` for a point:

```sql
SELECT ST_RelateMatch(
        ST_Relate(
            'POINT(1 1)',
            'POINT(1 1)'
        ),
        'TFFFTFFFT'
) AS relmatch;
 relmatch 
----------
 f
```

But `SELECT ST_Equals('POINT(1 1)','POINT(1 1)');` returns `True`.

On the other hand, on the Wikipedia page here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM it is stated that the Equals predicate is `T*F**FFF*`.

When trying this one in PostGIS, it returns `True` in the case of the point:

```sql
SELECT ST_RelateMatch(
        ST_Relate(
            'POINT(1 1)',
            'POINT(1 1)'
        ),
        'T*F**FFF*'
) AS relmatch;
 relmatch 
----------
 t
```

Also, here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-st-relate there is a third definition: `T*F**FFF2` for which the case of the point evaluates to `True` again.

Hence my question, because I'm a bit lost for the moment: is it possible that the OGC document is actually *wrong*? Or did I miss something?

Comment: Maybe there are different interpretations about how to make comparisons with a boundary of a point because that is empty.

Comment: Hmm, I see, but this is strange to my mind; how could the intersection of two ∅ be something other than ∅...